# Fast estimated count of rows in Cassandra table

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am surprised that this question wasn't raised before.

Suppose that we have a huge table in cassandra and we need to obtain an estimated number of rows in it (not exact, just approximation).

Apparently simple `select count(*) from table` is not efficient and can take a lot of time. We need something dirty and quick.

Datastax blog suggests [the following](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/counting-keys-in-cassandra):

> **I don’t care about the exact number, can I have a ballpark estimate?**
>
> Because Cassandra knows how many rows there are in each SSTable it is
>   possible to get an estimate. The ‘nodetool cfstats’ output tells you
>   these counts in the ‘Number of Keys (estimate)’ line. This is the sum
>   of rows in each SStable (again approximate due to the indexing used
>   but can’t be off by more than 128 by default).

My question: can we perform the same operation using [DataStax Enterprise Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-dse-driver)?

**P.S.** I can not change tables structure or whatever. Consider I use a legacy schema. In other words, I am not interested in workarounds like an adding counter or other special fields.

Comment: You could just store a counter if there's no automatic way.

Comment: @DonBranson this won't work if I have an already legacy db in prod

Comment: Yeah, not well. Initializing a counter to nodetool's estimate would allow a rough value. Depends on how much of a rough value you can tolerate. Definitely better if you can get something via the api.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cassandra exposes the approximate count (obtained from "nodetool cfstats") also via JMX. The code can hook into this JMX metric, to get counts programmatically.

> EstimatedPartitionCount Gauge Approximate number of keys in
>   table.

```
 {
    "type": "READ",
    "mbean": "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=*,scope=*,name=*",
    "attribute": "Count"
  }
```

Here is a [link](http://www.lebresne.net/~mcmanus/cassandra-doc-test/html/operating/metrics.html) on all JMX metrics exposed.

Comment: Any questions/comment on the solution provided? If otherwise can you please accept the answer.

Comment: JMX kind of hack and this won't work in the production code. But +1 for this solution.

Comment: @Andremoniy JMX is how all the monitoring tools hook into for Cassandra metrics

Comment: I don't need a monitoring, I need it to use in a production code in high loaded manner. So JMX won't work in my case

Comment: As you can imagine monitoring pretty much polls the data every few seconds. So, I don’t see a reason why an application can’t replicate that behavior.

Comment: Because I can not use JMX ports. I have only access to thrift

Comment: As per my observation, the value of EstimatedPartitionCount resets every time there is a Cassandra reboot. I think this is not a viable solution